# Eloqua Bulk API issue

Tags: api, bulk, eloqua

I am trying to fetch the data from Eloqua through bulk API 1.0 but I'm facing a problem, please follow my steps:

1) First I export the "syncedinstanceurl" from Eloqua and got successfully response like /contact/export/1234 with below code

2) Then I export the sync and got a response like /sync/12345 with below code

3) After that when I am trying to export the data from staging area with below code, out of 100 attempts the data (5000 as its limit) will come in one attempt only and didn't get in another attempt

```
syncedinstanceurl + "/data?page=1&pageSize=50000"
```

Could anybody tell me about this? Any paging issue is present or any data set issue.

Comment: its c# code so please provide any input

Comment: please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

Reduce your page size, maybe to 20,000 or 25,000, and try again.  Large pages, particular when many fields are included, are known to cause issues with data retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Bulk API 2.0 now that it's available.  It will support much larger page sizes when retrieving data.

Here's an article that discusses this work around as well as other Eloqua API tips: https://blogs.etouch.net/top-5-eloqua-pitfalls-faced-by-large-enterprises/